# Alt и title в теге picture

Tags: html, seo

Вывожу изображения через

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="img2.jpg" media="(max-width: 768px)">
  <source srcset="img1.jpg">
  <img  src="img1.jpg"  alt="img1"  title="img1"  >
</picture>
```

Нужно ли для внутренних тегов source писать alt и title?

Answer (score 0):

`alt` требуется указывать только для тега `img`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете самостоятельно проверить это на **[валидаторе ХТМЛ5](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)**. Но так как вы задаёте ваш вопрос в секции SEO, то я хочу обратить ваше внимание на то, что из этих этих элементов alt и title поисковые системы берут информацию, для так называемого **[Длинного Хвоста](http://patrickkeane.me/long-tail-seo-rank-difficult-keywords-beginner-guide/)**. Разумеется, если эти элементы валидны. То есть правильно кодируя эти элементы вы способствуете продвижению вашей страницы/сайта.